# How can I keep dropdown open and type?

Tags: css

How can I keep the dropdown open on clicking pumpkin icon be able to type something and close the dropdown when clicking anywhere else on screen except dropdown?
I know that something needs to be done here:

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button:focus

- .header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item

Note: trying to avoid using JS.
I tried to use &:focus in the parent class but it didn't work

```css
.header-bar__top {
  height: 3.5rem;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  z-index: 100;
  /* box-shadow: $header-bar-shadow; */
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.header-bar__container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 1152px;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down {
  display: inline;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button {
  color: darkblue;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  float: right;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button:focus
  + .header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 41px;
  height: 4.25rem;
  background-color: palegreen;
  display: inline-flex;
  opacity: 1;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-bar-utility {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  color: pink;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-bar-utility__icon {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.header-bar {
  height: 3.5rem;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css" />
    <title>Dropdown</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header-bar">
      <div class="header-bar__top">
        <div class="header-bar__container">
          <div class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down">
            <button
              class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button"
              tabindex="1"
            >
               1
            </button>
            <div class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item">
              <input placeholder="Search" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Text overlayed</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: button:focus + .header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item  |||
.header-bar-mobile-drop-down > :first-child:focus + div.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item |||

Neither helped, gave same result

Comment: It seems like you are focusing on the wrong thing here. CSS is meant to style your page, but what you want is interaction based, which is what JavaScript is for.

Comment: @EssXTee there are tons of examples of doing it in CSS, in my case I just need to figure out to do it not withe parent class but with the first child

Comment: If there are tons of examples, find one and look at the source code. It sounds like you already have your solution. Also, that still doesn't change the purpose of what CSS and JavaScript are for.

Comment: @EssXTee FYI. got a working answer below. Using only CSS
And yeah I didn't have a ready solution in JS, which I could achieve easily.
My aim was to use only CSS, there was no need for JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer which involves using one of new css attributes `:focus-within`
And moving the dropdown code above to make it a child of the clickable tag, which in my case is button

NOTE: this solution will not work for IE 11

Here is the code:

```css
.header-bar__top {
  height: 3.5rem;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  z-index: 100;
  /* box-shadow: $header-bar-shadow; */
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.header-bar__container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 1152px;
}

.header-bar {
  min-height: 3.5rem;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down {
  display: inline;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button {
  color: darkblue;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  float: right;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item {
  visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button:focus-within
  .header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 41px;
  height: 4.25rem;
  background-color: palegreen;
  display: inline-flex;
  opacity: 1;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-bar-utility {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  color: pink;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-bar-utility__icon {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.header-bar {
  height: 3.5rem;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.header-bar__toggle-menu {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  min-width: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css" />
    <title>Dropdown</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header-bar">
      <div class="header-bar__top">
        <div class="header-bar__container">
          <div class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down">
            <button class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button">
               1
              <div class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item">
                <input placeholder="Search" />
              </div>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Text overlayed</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay glad you found it.

Comment: I ended up using JS because :focus-within is not supported by IE 11.
I hope we will forget about its existence after 2 years, so annoying